# Optimizing a check using bit manipulations

Tags: c++, c, optimization, bit-manipulation, vectorization

I have the following code snippet as a part of one algorithm. I am using `pi_`, `pi`, `pi_stack[i]`, `is` and `is_stack[i]` (all `unsigned int`) as subsets of a set of size `N`.

- `N_MASK=(1<<N)-1` is a mask that determines what portion of the `unsigned int` is useful.
- `N_POLICY=(1<<N)`.

I want to find if there exists a subset `pi_` such that `((pi_^pi) & (is^N_MASK)) == 0 && ((pi_^pi_stack[i]) & is_stack[i]) == 0 && ((pi_^pi) & is)` holds true. Currently I am iterating over all possible subsets. What should be the relation between `is`, `pi_stack[i]`, `is_stack[i]` and `pi` so that no such `pi_` exists?

```
bool flag=false;
for(uint pi_=0; pi_<N_POLICY && !flag; pi_++){
    flag = flag || (
        ((pi_^pi) & (is^N_MASK)) == 0 &&
        ((pi_^pi_stack[i]) & is_stack[i]) == 0 &&
        ((pi_^pi) & is)
    );
}
```

I came up with:-
`flag = (((is_stack[i] & (is^N_MASK)) & (pi_stack[i]^pi))) || 0 == (is_stack[i] & (pi^pi_stack[i])) ;` But this does not work, but it gives an idea of what I am looking for. This code was meant to replace the loop above.

Comment: BTW `1<<N` has type *int*. You need to cast `1` or suffix it `1U` for the arithmetic to happen with unsigned.

Comment: Is it C or C++? Please take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252433/1000551

Comment: The `flag ||` is redundant, since the loop checks for `!flag`.

Comment: So N must be at most 32? And `i`, `is` and `pi` are constants, or just fixed for a given call?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I used a `#define` to set that (No overhead of memory access), and `N` will be atmost 20 (This was a part of larger program, and N=6 is already taking too lon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution can be computed directly with no loops other than iterating through `pi_stack[i]` and `is_stack[i]`.

A criterion of the form `(pi_ ^ v) & m` requires that `pi_` and `v` have the same values in each bit position for which the bit is set in `m`.  We can represent that:

```
uint RequiredBits   = m; // Mask of bits that must have certain values.
uint RequiredValues = v & m; // Record of the values the bits must have.
```

Your tests show two such criteria:

```
((pi_ ^ pi) & (is ^ N_MASK)) == 0

((pi_ ^ pi_stack[i]) & is_stack[i]) == 0
```

Suppose we have already represented the first criterion:

```
uint RequiredBits   = is ^ N_MASK;
uint RequiredValues = pi & RequiredBits;
```

Now we want to also require the second criterion. For brevity, let’s assign `v = pi_stack[i]` and `m = is_stack[i]`. We have two problems: Is it possible to satisfy both criteria simultaneously?  And, if so, what one criterion is the combination of both?

If `m` and `RequiredBits` do not have any set bits in common, then there is no conflict, because `pi_` is free to have the required values in whatever bit positions they each control. If they do have set bits in common, then `v` and `RequiredValue` must be the same in those bits, because `pi_` cannot have both 0 and 1 in the same position. So a test for conflict is:

```
if (((v ^ RequiredValues) & (m & RequiredBits)) != 0)
    print/exit/return/whatever; // Report no solution is possible.
```

If the two criteria are consistent, then we can combine them:

```
RequiredValues = RequiredValues | (v & m);
RequiredBits   = RequiredBits | m;
```

If there are multiple instances of the criteria involving `pi_stack[i]` and `is_stack[i]` for different values of `i`, then the above can be repeated.

Finally, we have the criterion  `pi_ ^ pi) & is`. This says that `pi_` an `pi` must differ in at least one bit position for which the bit is set in `is`. This position must be a position that is not set in `RequiredBits`, because the earlier criteria require that `pi_` and `pi` be the same in those positions, and it is not possible for `pi_` and `pi` to be both the same and to differ in the same position.

Therefore, `pi_` and `pi` must differ in at least one bit that is in `is & ~RequiredBits`. If `is & ~RequiredBits` is zero, this is not possible, because then there are no positions in `is` that `pi_` and `pi` are allowed to differ in. So we test:

```
if ((is & ~RequiredBits) == 0)
    print/exit/return/whatever; // Report no solution is possible.
```

Otherwise, we construct some differences between `pi_` and `pi` in the required (by `is`) and available (by `~RequiredBits`) positions:

```
uint Differences = ~pi & (is & ~RequiredBits);
```

Then a solution is:

```
uint pi_ = RequiredValues | Differences;
```

All possible solutions could be iterated by:

- Iterate all the bits of `pi_` other than those in `is | RequiredBits` through all possible values.
- Iterate all the bits of `pi_` that are in `is & ~RequiredBits` through all possible values except `pi & (is & ~RequiredBits)` (because that is one in which all the bits specified by `is & ~RequiredBits` have the values they do in `pi`, but we want at least one to be different).

Comment: This was awesome! I tried to think on the same line, but was kind of struck on the third condition